# Cosine elliptic solutions to Mathieu's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

In McLachlan's book 'Theory and Applications of Mathieu's equation', a solution of the form in the image below is derived.

[image]

The author mentions that 'ce' stands for "cosine elliptic", but does not say why it is called so. A google search on that term yielded https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticCosine.html which says "An even Mathieu function $ce_r(z,q)$ with characteristic value $a_r$" which was not very useful.

I want to know what a cosine elliptic is and why is the solution is called so.

Comment: The section on Mathieu's equation did not mention why it is called cosine-elliptic. Did I miss something?

Comment: Oh alright. I'll take another look at it then

Comment: Perfect. Found it. Thanks